# RestKit date conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, date-conversion

A Date value of `1435819788000` was converted by RestKit as `47469-04-26 14:00:00 +0000`. I guess the problem is the difference between Java's date representation that uses milliseconds and Unix's date representation which uses seconds. I think I need to set a converter. How can I do that? (I see rk transformers on GitHub but I don't know how to use them or where to find an appropriate transformer.)

**Edit:** This is the code that does the rest call

```
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some url"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];

    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Price class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"ron95", @"ron95": @"ron92", @"dieselNormal": @"dieselNormal", @"dieselSpecial": @"dieselSpecial", @"postDate": @"postDate"}];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];
    [objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    NSArray *prices = [mappingResult array];
```

**Edit:** I think I have it working now. The following is how I do it.

```
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Price class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"ron95", @"ron95": @"ron92", @"dieselNormal": @"dieselNormal", @"dieselSpecial": @"dieselSpecial"}];

    RKBlockValueTransformer *numberToDateValueTransformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class sourceClass, __unsafe_unretained Class destinationClass) {
        // This transformer handles `NSNumber` <-> `NSDate` transformations
        return (([sourceClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && [destinationClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSDate class]]) ||
                ([sourceClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSDate class]] && [destinationClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]]));
    } transformationBlock:^BOOL(id inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, __unsafe_unretained Class outputValueClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        RKValueTransformerTestInputValueIsKindOfClass(inputValue, (@[ [NSNumber class], [NSDate class] ]), error);
        RKValueTransformerTestOutputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputValueClass, (@[ [NSNumber class], [NSDate class] ]), error);
        if ([outputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
            if ([inputValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
                *outputValue = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[inputValue doubleValue] / 1000];
            }
        } else if ([outputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            *outputValue = @([inputValue timeIntervalSince1970]);
        }
        return YES;
    }];


    RKAttributeMapping *postDateMapping = [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"postDate" toKeyPath:@"postDate"];
    postDateMapping.valueTransformer = numberToDateValueTransformer;
    [mapping addPropertyMapping:postDateMapping];
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: Did you search for examples or people previously trying to use Java timestamps?

Comment: @Wain No one has used iOS with Java timestamps in my country. They use Rails for the server side.